# Autowire MessageSource in a custom Authentication Entry Point

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to send a custom error for anonymous unauthorized requests through a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint

```
public class AccessDeniedAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

  @Autowired
  private Messages messages;

  @Override
  public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request,
                   final HttpServletResponse response,
                   final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final ApplicationErrorResponse error = new ApplicationErrorResponse(
        Message.PERMISSION_FAILED.toString(),
        messages.get(Message.PERMISSION_FAILED.toString()));

    if (response.getWriter() != null) {
        response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(error));
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
}
```

The Messages bean encapsulates the default MessageSource (messages.properties) and returns the values through a MessageSourceAccessor

```
@Component
public class Messages {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);
    }

    public String get(String code) {
        return accessor.getMessage(code);
    }
}
```

However when an AccessDendiedException is raised and the `commence` method in the AccessDeniedAuthenticationEntryPoint is called, the injected/autowired Messages object is `null`. 
I just couldn't get Spring to successfully inject Messages in a custom Authentication Entry Point. 
I even tried registering a bean of type MessageSource

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

and tried autowiring it in the AuthenticationEntryPoint but it didn't work too.

How can I successfully inject/autowire a MessageSource in a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint?

Comment: You can only autowire spring beans into other spring-managed beans. Is AccessDeniedAuthenticationEntryPoint managed by spring or how do you create it?

Comment: Did you annotate `AccessDeniedAuthenticationEntryPoint` with `@Component` and inject it in your configuration?

Comment: Thanks. I completely overlooked it. I did have `@Component` annotation on `AccessDeniedAuthenticationEntryPoint`, however it was not autowired in the configuration. It was being instantiated with `new` keyword and probably that's why Spring wasn't managing it as a bean.